# How to set different roles for Wordpress custom registration template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Searching for solution how to set two different roles to custom WordPress template. I don't want to use a plugin, and try to do it my self.

As you can see I have two tabs **engineer** and **customer** with sign up details below, which i can select with javascript.

If users wants to be register account as **customer**, I want to set role them to **Subscriber**.
If users wants to be register account as **engineer**, I want to set role them to **Editor**.

I need to do that automatically, not manually for each customer in admin, but I don't have coding skills. Someone can help me to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

/*

Template name: SIGNUP

*/


get_header();
global $wpdb;

if ($_POST) {

    $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtUsername']);
    $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
    $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtPassword']);
    $ConfPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']);

    $error = array();
    if (strpos($username, ' ') !== FALSE) {
        $error['username_space'] = "Username has Space";
    }

    if (empty($username)) {
        $error['username_empty'] = "Needed Username must";
    }

    if (username_exists($username)) {
        $error['username_exists'] = "Username already exists";
    }

    if (!is_email($email)) {
        $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
    }

    if (email_exists($email)) {
        $error['email_existence'] = "Email already exists";
    }

    if (empty($password)) {
        $error['password_empty'] = "Needed Password must";
    }

    if (count($error) == 0) {

        wp_create_user($username, $password, $email);
        echo "User Created Successfully";
        exit();
    }else{

        print_r($error);

    }
}
?>
<section>

                        <div class="container mb-5">

                            <div class="heading">

                                <h1 class="text-center reg-name">Sign Up</h1>

                            </div>


                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="tabs col text-center mt-5 mb-5">

                                    <button id="openTab" class="tablinks usr-btn col-3" onclick="openTab(event, 'engineer')">For engineer

                                    <button class="tablinks usr-btn col-3" onclick="openTab(event, 'customer')">For customer</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>  

                            <div class="row">

                                <div id="engineer" class="col-6 tabcontent text-center m-auto">

                                    <form method="post">

                                        <p>

                                            <label>Enter engineer Username</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="text" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername" />

                                            </div>

                                            <label>Enter engineer Email</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" />

                                            </div>

                                            <label>Enter engineer Password</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" />

                                            </div>

                                        </p>

                                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">

                                    </form>

                                </div>



                                <div id="customer" class="col-6 tabcontent text-center m-auto">

                                    <form method="post">

                                        <p>

                                            <label>Enter customer Username</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="text" name="txtUsername" id="txtUsername" />

                                            </div>

                                            <label>Enter customer Email</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" />

                                            </div>

                                            <label>Enter customer Password</label>

                                            <div>

                                                <input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" />

                                            </div>

                                        </p>

                                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit">

                                    </form>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

</section>


<script>
function openTab(evt, rolesName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(rolesName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("openTab").click();
</script>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image: Sign up page sample from code]

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but allowing people to have the automatic role of "Editor" is really bad practice, especially if this is open to the public. Editors have capabilities that could potentially compromise your site. Is there a reason you are doing it this way? There might be a better solution.

Comment: Later I will create another roles for this tabs, with different names and restriction. At this time search for solution how to solve this sign up page problem and how to set differnt roles for it?